# loadHTMLString warn "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument" IOS9 Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I've just installed xcode 7 with ios 9.1 and I get this warning on a webview:

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

This is the code that fires the error:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(exitView)
        [ytView.webView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
}
```

This way when the user goes back the webView (that plays a YT video) stops, it worked fine before, why does it gives this warning now?
How can I fix it?

Comment: why not change to [ytView.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ytView.webView loadHTMLString:"" baseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"] ];
```

taken from 
http://iaintheindie.com/2015/08/16/updating-apps-for-ios-9/

regards

Comment: this one setting the value for baseURL attribute. But still warning message is there for loadHTMLString attribute.

Comment: loadHTMLString:""

Answer (score 1):

change the return type in CDVInAppBrowser.m at lines..

```
732    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
1002  (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but clearly from the warning message, now you can not send the nil value to this method. Why don't you just remove the UIWebView or set UIWebView to nil in your viewWillDisappear.